# Python Scraping - Selenium - Element is not clickable at point

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, clickable

I'm trying to click the next button on a webpage multiple times, I need scrape the page after each click. The following code is shortened but illustrates my situation. I am able to scrape the required tag after the first click, but then the second click fails. Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('http://www.agoda.com/the-coast-resort-koh-phangan/hotel/koh-phangan-th.html') 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='next-page']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='next-page']").click()

browser.quit()
```

I get this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point
```

Although when I use beautifulSoup and get the source code after the first click the element I am trying to click again is clearly there to click.

I've read on other answers I might need to wait some time but not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you click the next page starts to load, you can't click on a link that is on a page that is still loading or on a link on a page that is about to be replaced by another page! So the message is quite correct. So you just have to wait for the next page to appear before you can click on the next link. You can just sleep for N seconds or, much better, wait for the element to appear before clicking on it again.

Have a look at: [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)

So there you would probably want to use **element_to_be_clickable** on each attempt to click. What happens is it waits N seconds for it to be clickable and if it does not take that state in that time it throws an exception.

Here is a good blog post on all this: [How to get Selenium to wait for page load after a click](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html)

Here is a simple example of how you can use that. Here you  have just clicked on the link for the first time, and then after that to wait for the next to load you can:

```
    xpath = "//a[@id='next-page']"
    WebDriverWait(browser.webdriver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, Im looking at the blog post, although for a newbie this is pretty difficult to grasp, since im not using find_element_by_id but using find_element_by_xpath so its not at all clear to me how to adapt the (By.ID, 'thing-on-new-page'),'expected new text' part of the example. Still thank you for the info and links they are definitely useful

Comment: you just literally replace one with the other, and pass in the xpath.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a more specific example.

Comment: ah, "expected conditions", a powerful and little-used portion of Selenium. upvoted to remind me to refer back to this answer!

Comment: Can't you add a .click() to the end of the WebDriverWait statement? I know you can in Java... I'm not sure about python. You are basically searching for the same element twice.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'webdriver'

Comment: If I remove the webdriver and just use WebDriverWait(browser, 10) i get StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM. Or sometimes i get another error: WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point

Comment: That's the correct way of doing it, your webdriver is called browser. What you should do is enter an interactive session (I recommend Ipython) and load your webpage via Selenium commands in that session. Then as you work out each command and it works, add it to your script. Try to add a check to make sure the subsequent page has loaded (i.e. after you click the next page button) before attempting to click the next button. That's where those errors are from.

Comment: So something like "check the page has loaded, find the next button, wait for it to be clickable, click it, check the page has loaded, find the next button" and so on. Otherwise you get errors trying to select on a page that is going away (which seems to be what is happening for you).

Comment: Im going to except your answer as its probably right, even though I cant get my code to work. Im using ipython notebook so I can check each part of the code it working. I think the problem might be a scroll issue, since when I look at firefox the button im trying to click is not in view as for some reason the page has been scrolled down ever so slightly. So ive posted a new question as I now have problems trying to scroll! Ah the joys of programming ;-)

Comment: Just found out why I was having these problems. Theres some css horizontal menu bar that floats at the top of the page (regardless of where the page is scrolled to) this was always blocking my elemet to be clicked on, so although selemium could find my element to click on it could not actually click it. This was sorted out by scrolling not the element I wante dto click on but to one element slightly higher up the page, so my element then came into view

Comment: there is a "scroll element into view" command also that might be useful

Comment: @JeffC yes, you usually can but I was just trying to keep the example simple